# Python DictWriter: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:Users\\...\\Desktop\\file.csv'

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I know this has been asked and answered a couple of times. Still, the solutions posted so far do not fix my problem.
I'm getting this error code when trying to open a csv-file with Python DictWriter.

I tried at least the following variations so far:

```
with open(r"‪C:/Users/.../Desktop/file.csv", 'w') as xfile:
```

```
with open("‪C:\\\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\file.csv", 'w') as xfile:
```

```
with open(r"‪C:\Users\...\Desktop\file.csv", 'w') as xfile:
```

Quotes requested by stackoverflow.
I also used append method instead of write with no effect.
The three dorts are a placeholder, the path is complete and correct.

So what could be the problem here?
Any help would be much appreciated!
Regards
Thomas

Comment: The `\u202a` bit in your error message says that you have an invisible Unicode control character before the `C:` in your filename.  Try deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! I could indeed delete an invisible character at the start of my path, without the cursor moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to delete the invisible control character U+202A (Left-to-Right Embedding) at the start of the path.

[This blog post from Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924) provides one possible explanation for this character turning up at the start of a Windows file path.